# fontspec + xelatex: won't use small caps TTF

Tags: fonts, xetex, formatting, fontspec

I wanted to use the Cormorant font family in my LaTeX document.

I later learned that a Geramond variety of this family appears in the TeXLive distribution, but I was unaware at the time, and anyway I believe that these families are not identical, the Geramond lacking letter definitions for small caps.

I downloaded and unpacked the font files from the [release download page](https://github.com/CatharsisFonts/Cormorant/releases) (archive name `Cormorant_Install_v3.601.zip`) into the folder containing my document, and inserted the following lines into my LaTeX file:

```latex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Cormorant-Regular.ttf}[
      BoldFont = Cormorant-Bold.ttf ,
      ItalicFont = Cormorant-Italic.ttf ,
      BoldItalicFont = Cormorant-BoldItalic.ttf,
    ]
```

I created some small caps formatting, which looked reasonable after running through XeLaTeX, but as I understood that LaTeX would not have a source of correct small caps lettering, it must be faking the small caps based on the regular style font. I wanted to achieve a superior appearance from the correct source for this letter appearance, which is given in a separate font file.

I added the additional field to the optional parameter list:

```
SmallCapsFont = CormorantSC-Regular.ttf
```

Yet, I discovered no difference in the output.

I tried a variety of further additions to the list, dealing with font features, based on my frustrated attempt to benefit from the `fontspec` documentation, but I found no variation that produced output with a different effect.

I looked at the results under magnification, and began to wonder whether somehow the effect I was seeing was actually correct small caps.  However, after inspecting the font file as best I could, I came to understand that a TTF-format file cannot embed both regular letters and small caps.

As such, the small caps output I have now is either fake, or the font is somehow being found in another source.  Yet I have no evidence of either.

I can prove that the option has some effect because I can make LaTeX generate italics from the `\textsc` command by using the following form:

```
SmallCapsFont = Cormorant-Italics.ttf
```

I created an overall test case, as follows.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{landscape,a5paper}

\setmainfont{Cormorant-Regular.ttf}[
   BoldFont = Cormorant-Bold.ttf ,
    ItalicFont = Cormorant-Italic.ttf ,
    BoldItalicFont = Cormorant-BoldItalic.ttf,
]

\begin{document}

\Large

\noindent The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog. \vspace{1em}

\noindent \textbf{The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog.} \vspace{1em}

\noindent \textit{The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog.} \vspace{1em}

\noindent \textsc{The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog.} \vspace{1em}

\end{document}
```

Adding the following line to the optional parameter list of `\setmainfont` should have an effect, but has none.

```
SmallCapsFont = CormorantSC-Regular.ttf
```

---

## Results

### Without use of small caps font file

[image: Without use of small caps font file]

### With use of small caps font file

[image: With use of small caps font file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to change anything since `Cormorant-Regular.ttf` does contain the `smcp` feature necessary for `fontspec` to use real small caps:

```
$ otfinfo -f  Cormorant_Install_v3.601/1.\ TrueType\ Font\ Files/Cormorant-Regular.ttf | grep smcp
smcp    Small Capitals
```

An alternative way to see this is provided by fontforge that you mention in the comments. With `Metrics -> New Metrics Window` you can not only test font metrics but also many font features. Typing some text gives you:

[image]

Activating the `smcp` feature in the left hand column gives:

[image]

While the typed characters at the top stay the same, the glyphs used to represent these characters have changed: `/h` has been replaced with `/h.sc` etc.

If the feature where not there, `fontspec` would not fake small caps all by itself. The `CormorantSC-Regular.ttf` font present in the distribution is meant as a convenience feature for people having to use software that does not understand OpenType features like `smcp`.

Concerning your (implicit) question how a TrueType font can contain both regular and small caps glyphs. This has been possible for a long time. "Palatino Linotype" is an example for such a font. One has to remember that OpenType is TrueType plus the abbility to store glyphs as cubic splines and additional font features like `smcp`. A TrueType font with glyphs stored as quadratic splines but OpenType font features can still be treated as normal TrueType font by applications that do not understand OpenType.

Comment: I'm glad you explained.  I opened the font in Font Forge and in a few utilities included in my Linux desktop, and also ran a text utility called `ttfdump`.  I never saw any indication whatsoever of the small caps included in these files.  Is there a graphical application that can preview the small caps if they're not in a separate file?

Comment: What you're saying about OTF is that the format extends TTF, and that some files use new features but are backward compatible, in which case they use the same `.ttf` extension; whereas some features like cubic splines cannot be rendered in a TTF-only engine and in such cases the files must use the new `.otf` extension?

Comment: @epl Your description of the OTF--TTF relation is spot on. Concerning other ways of seeing these features I have added some screenshots using FontForge.